# Looping through Terraform vars

Tags: variables, terraform

I have a loop inside a user-data template and I would need that `groups` will have the value `"test1" "test2"`. Using the following syntax I am getting this result, but without double quotes: `test1 test2`.

```
# main.tf
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("test-user-data.sh.tpl")
  vars = {
    ...
    groups          = join(" ", var.groups)
    ...  
}

# variables.tf
variable "groups" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

Is any way that I can get also the double quotes for each group?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the relevant snippet in `test-user-data.sh.tpl`?

Comment: Inside of the template I am using a Python script that consumes "groups" value as an input argument.

Comment: Can you show `test-user-data.sh.tpl`? Also you haven't provided any errors or any description of what's wrong with your current code? What is current output? What is expected outcome?